# Licensing dual boot Windows 8

Tags: licensing, windows-8

I would like to have two instances of Windows 8 Pro in the same machine, one for regular use and another for development.

I'm considering either using Hyper-V or a dual boot configuration. Do I need two Windows 8 Pro licenses?

Comment: I can't find any specifics about dual booting in that question, it is very general

Comment: That's the idea, to be honest. It's impossible to cover every single different licensing area so we have to use a "catch-all" question.

Comment: Yes, and it seems it has developed quite well, but I need (and I'm sure other people would also find it helpful) a straight answer, as this specific topic is not so complex neither general

Comment: @DortróGrijando, we here just _can not_ give any licensing advise. That is a legal issue, you have to either ask the vendor or hire a lawyer.

Comment: Aha, I didn't know that, sorry :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No. Pretty much all installs - physical - I know of are per machine. Dual boot I never heard to require two licenses.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. What if the dual boot is implemented using a VHD file?